# Adding setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape)

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, r.java-file

I'm sure this is probably a simple thing to ask, but I've been scratching my head at it for a while now and don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Basically I am following some examples to build a table in android, when I come to `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape)` it shows an error and I'm unsure where to add this in my xml sheets. Can anyone put me out of my misery please? :-/

Here is the snippet:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape); // This is my problem here
tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
tv.setText("R " + i + ", C" + j);

row.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Could you add the error you are receiving in your question?

Comment: The exact error is "cell_shape cannot be resolved or is not a field "

Comment: There should be a image in your drawable folder with the name `cell_shape`

Comment: If that is the error, then it could mean that it cannot find any images called cell_shape in any of your drawable folders

Comment: you need to put your cell_shape.xml inside the res/drawable folder

Comment: plz check your imports for proper R.java file, make sure you are not importing android.R.java file

Comment: @RiteshGune yes I have the correct file being imported.

Comment: Ok. plz check for cell_shape in R.java file. See if it is there or not

Comment: @RiteshGune no there isnt any. And I'm blocked from manually editing the R file. I have nothing for cell_shape in my res/drawable file either that maybe it?

Comment: You need to put something in your drawable folder, if it doesn't exist it won't be able to find it

Comment: You must place cell_shape in drawable folder

Comment: okie dokie. So add cell_shape.xml with an int val for cell_shape?

Comment: what is your minimum sdk version in app? and is there cell_shape image present in any drawable folder?

Comment: is ***cell_shape*** an image or XML?

Comment: it wasnt indicated in the example. And the minimum sdk is 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make sure that **cell_shape** is present inside your **/res/drawable** folder
2. make sure you import the proper **`R.java`** **`yourpkgname.R`** not **`android.R`**
3. if still not working then clean your project.

Let me know if it workes for you.